# opencv cv::findcontours program crashes

Tags: c++, opencv, contour

```
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
 std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
    cv::findContours(ThreshIm,contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

   cv::fillPoly(ThreshIm,contours,Scalar(255));
    cv::drawContours(frame,contours,-1,Scalar(0,255,0),3);

 //  cv::RotatedRect box= cv::minAreaRect(Mat(contours[0]));
```

While taking a live input from camera, the program runs successfully until the cv::RotatatedRect is not included in the code,but as soon as the program is run with this line, the program crashes. What might be happening?

Comment: What error are you getting? At the moment that's context free code so there's not a lot to go on.

Comment: the program simply starts and terminates. Im using qtcreator IDE. the error is:Starting /home/ayush/Desktop/buoy-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_in_PATH__System__Release/yo...
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
The program has unexpectedly finished.
/home/ayush/Desktop/buoy-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_in_PATH__System__Release/yo exited with code 0

Comment: @user3105042 did you fix this? I am having a similar problem with `findContours()`